# numpy savetxt not working

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to save a 600x5 array that is composed of strings. It has dtype('S32') and when I try to save the array it says:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S32')
           and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e')
```

What exactly is this porblem? It should work with strings and usually does.

```
array = []
for items in range(100):
    ar = np.array(['name', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'])
    array = np.append(array, ar)
a = np.reshape(array, (100,5))
np.savetxt('out.txt', a)
```

Comment: The error without your code is useless. Add your code if you want someone to give you a feedback.

Comment: Added code in the main post

Comment: What 'usually' works with strings?  Plain array print?  or `savetxt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the format by `np.savetxt('out.txt', a, fmt='%s')` while the default is `fmt='%.18e`.